# Combine 4 cursor imgs in one (css-sprites)

Tags: image, css, cursor, css-sprites

Is there any way to combine 4 png cursors into one larger image and style each cursor by positioning the img's x,y?

```
cursor:url(path/arrow-left.png), auto;
cursor:url(path/arrow-down.png), auto;
cursor:url(path/arrow-right.png), auto;
cursor:url(path/arrow-up.png), auto;
```

Alternatively can I use just on arrow.png and rotate in for the respective cursor?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly you are looking for http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: Exactly but with cursors. Is that doable?

Comment: I've done a lot of digging and played around with it and I do not believe there is a way to sprite your cursor unfortunately